# systemtap ubuntu error

Tags: 16.04, 11.10, kernel

after install systemtap on ubuntu,test example hello-stap.stp。but there are some errors。

how can I fix this?

thanks

systemtap version

```
Systemtap translator/driver (version 2.9/0.165, Debian version 2.9-2ubuntu2 (xenial))
Copyright (C) 2005-2015 Red Hat, Inc. and others
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
enabled features: AVAHI LIBSQLITE3 NLS NSS TR1_UNORDERED_MAP
```

hello-stap.stp

```
probe begin
{
    print("hello world\n")
    exit()
}
```

this is error info。

Error 1:

```
   In file included from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/runtime.h:204:0,
                    from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/runtime.h:24,
                    from /tmp/stapd8LhT7/stap_24feca2d4e5abb002d28b0bc184e6d61_945_src.c:25:
    /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/access_process_vm.h: In function ‘__access_process_vm_’:
    /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/access_process_vm.h:35:29: error: passing argument 1 of ‘get_user_pages’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
        ret = get_user_pages (tsk, mm, addr, 1, write, 1, &page, &vma);


                 ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Error 2:

```
 In file included from ./include/linux/pid_namespace.h:6:0,
                    from ./include/linux/ptrace.h:8,
                    from ./include/linux/ftrace.h:13,
                    from ./include/linux/kprobes.h:42,
                    from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/runtime.h:21,
                    from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/runtime.h:24,
                    from /tmp/stapd8LhT7/stap_24feca2d4e5abb002d28b0bc184e6d61_945_src.c:25:
    ./include/linux/mm.h:1293:6: note: expected ‘long unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘struct task_struct *’
    long get_user_pages(unsigned long start, unsigned long nr_pages,
        ^
```

Error 3:
    In file included from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/runtime.h:204:0,
                    from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/runtime.h:24,
                    from /tmp/stapd8LhT7/stap_24feca2d4e5abb002d28b0bc184e6d61_945_src.c:25:
    /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/access_process_vm.h:35:34: error: passing argument 2 of ‘get_user_pages’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
        ret = get_user_pages (tsk, mm, addr, 1, write, 1, &page, &vma);
                                    ^
Error 4:

```
 In file included from ./include/linux/pid_namespace.h:6:0,
                    from ./include/linux/ptrace.h:8,
                    from ./include/linux/ftrace.h:13,
                    from ./include/linux/kprobes.h:42,
                    from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/runtime.h:21,
                    from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/runtime.h:24,
                    from /tmp/stapd8LhT7/stap_24feca2d4e5abb002d28b0bc184e6d61_945_src.c:25:
    ./include/linux/mm.h:1293:6: note: expected ‘long unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘struct mm_struct *’
    long get_user_pages(unsigned long start, unsigned long nr_pages,
        ^
```

Error 5:

```
 In file included from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/runtime.h:204:0,
                    from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/runtime.h:24,
                    from /tmp/stapd8LhT7/stap_24feca2d4e5abb002d28b0bc184e6d61_945_src.c:25:
    /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/access_process_vm.h:35:44: error: passing argument 4 of ‘get_user_pages’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
        ret = get_user_pages (tsk, mm, addr, 1, write, 1, &page, &vma);
                                                ^
```

Error 6:

```
In file included from ./include/linux/pid_namespace.h:6:0,
                from ./include/linux/ptrace.h:8,
                from ./include/linux/ftrace.h:13,
                from ./include/linux/kprobes.h:42,
                from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/runtime.h:21,
                from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/runtime.h:24,
                from /tmp/stapd8LhT7/stap_24feca2d4e5abb002d28b0bc184e6d61_945_src.c:25:
./include/linux/mm.h:1293:6: note: expected ‘struct page **’ but argument is of type ‘int’
long get_user_pages(unsigned long start, unsigned long nr_pages,
    ^
```

Error 7:

```
 In file included from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/runtime.h:204:0,
                    from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/runtime.h:24,
                    from /tmp/stapd8LhT7/stap_24feca2d4e5abb002d28b0bc184e6d61_945_src.c:25:
    /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/access_process_vm.h:35:47: error: passing argument 5 of ‘get_user_pages’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
        ret = get_user_pages (tsk, mm, addr, 1, write, 1, &page, &vma);
                                                ^
```

Error 8:

```
 In file included from ./include/linux/pid_namespace.h:6:0,
                    from ./include/linux/ptrace.h:8,
                    from ./include/linux/ftrace.h:13,
                    from ./include/linux/kprobes.h:42,
                    from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/runtime.h:21,
                    from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/runtime.h:24,
                    from /tmp/stapd8LhT7/stap_24feca2d4e5abb002d28b0bc184e6d61_945_src.c:25:
    ./include/linux/mm.h:1293:6: note: expected ‘struct vm_area_struct **’ but argument is of type ‘int’
    long get_user_pages(unsigned long start, unsigned long nr_pages,
        ^
```

Error 9:

```
 In file included from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/runtime.h:204:0,
                    from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/runtime.h:24,
                    from /tmp/stapd8LhT7/stap_24feca2d4e5abb002d28b0bc184e6d61_945_src.c:25:
    /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/access_process_vm.h:35:13: error: too many arguments to function ‘get_user_pages’
        ret = get_user_pages (tsk, mm, addr, 1, write, 1, &page, &vma);
                ^
```

Error 10:

```
 In file included from ./include/linux/pid_namespace.h:6:0,
                    from ./include/linux/ptrace.h:8,
                    from ./include/linux/ftrace.h:13,
                    from ./include/linux/kprobes.h:42,
                    from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/runtime.h:21,
                    from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/runtime.h:24,
                    from /tmp/stapd8LhT7/stap_24feca2d4e5abb002d28b0bc184e6d61_945_src.c:25:
    ./include/linux/mm.h:1293:6: note: declared here
    long get_user_pages(unsigned long start, unsigned long nr_pages,
        ^
```

Error 11:

```
 In file included from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/runtime.h:204:0,
                    from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/runtime.h:24,
                    from /tmp/stapd8LhT7/stap_24feca2d4e5abb002d28b0bc184e6d61_945_src.c:25:
    /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/access_process_vm.h:55:7: error: implicit declaration of function ‘page_cache_release’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
        page_cache_release (page);
        ^
```

Error 12:

```
 In file included from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/linux/print.c:17:0,
                    from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/print.c:17,
                    from /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/runtime_context.h:22,
                    from /tmp/stapd8LhT7/stap_24feca2d4e5abb002d28b0bc184e6d61_945_src.c:55:
    /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/transport/transport.c: In function ‘_stp_lock_inode’:
    /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/transport/transport.c:506:19: error: ‘struct inode’ has no member named ‘i_mutex’
    mutex_lock(&inode->i_mutex);
                    ^
```

Error 13:

```
 /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/transport/transport.c: In function ‘_stp_unlock_inode’:
    /usr/share/systemtap/runtime/transport/transport.c:515:21: error: ‘struct inode’ has no member named ‘i_mutex’
    mutex_unlock(&inode->i_mutex);
                        ^
```

Tip:

```
  cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
    scripts/Makefile.build:294: recipe for target '/tmp/stapd8LhT7/stap_24feca2d4e5abb002d28b0bc184e6d61_945_src.o' failed
    make[1]: *** [/tmp/stapd8LhT7/stap_24feca2d4e5abb002d28b0bc184e6d61_945_src.o] Error 1
    Makefile:1524: recipe for target '_module_/tmp/stapd8LhT7' failed
    make: *** [_module_/tmp/stapd8LhT7] Error 2
    WARNING: kbuild exited with status: 2
    Pass 4: compilation failed.  [man error::pass4]
    Tip: /usr/share/doc/systemtap/README.Debian should help you get started.
```

Answer (score 0):

I know what the problem is, but not the solution.

Ubuntu has an out-dated version of Systemtap, which means it attempts to compile against current kernel headers. The kernel function get_user_pages() has changed, but systemtap is still attempting to use the old version.

This is causing compilation errors. I do not know how to fix this. Ubuntu has not updated their package. The only solution I can think of is compiling a newer version of systemtap on your own or switching distributions.